# Cannot connect to S3 bucket via Transmit, only via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, ftp-client

I have this S3 bucket that I can connect to through AWS CLI. First I go to Terminal and set it up:

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************]: ACCESS_KEY
AWS Secret Access Key [****************]: SECRET_KEY
Default region name [None]:
Default output format [None]:
```

After that I can do the regular operations on it from Terminal. To list the folders at the root of the S3 bucket, I just go to Terminal and write:

```
aws s3 ls s3://name-of-my-bucket
```

The other AWS CLI operations also work just fine. But when I try to set this S3 bucket up in Transmit, it doesn't seem to work. In Transmit you can set up an S3 bucket, so I choose that preset for starters, then add my Access Key ID and my Secret Key. For Address I've tried everything: s3.amazonaws.com, name-of-my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com, name-of-my-bucket, etc. When I try to use the Address s3://name-of-my-bucket it changes to the SFTP preset, which obviously won't work.

Since I know the Access Key ID and Secret Key are correct, I'm assuming that my mistake must be in the Address field, but I cannot figure it out. Can you help?

I've had other S3 buckets and never had this problem, they worked just fine and were easy to set up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- In Quick Connect, select a Protocol of `Amazon S3`
- Set Credentials. In the Remote Path, put `name-of-my-bucket`

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to **Transmit**, I presume you are referring to the [Transmit file transfer app for MacOS](https://panic.com/transmit/).

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Installed Transmit
- In **Quick Connect** I selected a **Protocol** of `Amazon S3`
- Clicked **Connect**

[image: Transmit login]

- It prompted me for an Access Key and Secret Key, which I entered
- It then **presented me with a list of my Amazon S3 buckets**
- I was then able to **double-click** the name of a bucket and the contents was displayed

Comment: Hi John.  Yes, you are correct. I'm referring to Panic Transmit. Is the FTP client I use normally. The way you describe is pretty much the standard way to do this, yes. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. It does not manage to authenticate. I solved this by forgetting about Transmit and instead using Chrome extension "My S3 Browser", works perfectly: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-s3-browser/lgkbddebikceepncgppakonioaopmbkk?hl=en

Comment: It didn't work for me until I entered in the bucket name as remote path.  Which is fine, except that the error seems to be about auth credentials being incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The current Transmit documentation mentions that it needs to list the bucket to determine the bucket region for users.

https://help.panic.com/general/s3/

So add "s3:ListBucket" as an action to the IAM policy, then specify the Remote Path as "/" followed by your S3 bucket name when you log in.

Comment: But one must already have this to be able to use cli